# porting from ios to windows

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I'm about to write code for Windows that has somewhat similar functionality to the one existing in already written application for iPhone. I'm thinking of separating common functionality to form a component and compile it to both to iPhone and to Windows. This code is written in Objective C and uses RestKit and Core Data (and probably sqlite). Is compiling it for Windows a viable task? As I understand it GCC could compile Objective C on Windows but I'm unsure about the RestKit and Core Data api availability on Windows. I have seen two names that could be of use: GNUStep and Cocotron but I don't know if they will play well together with RestKit.

Note: I have no idea about iOS development so I might be confusing things. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not easily be able to share this functionality between your applications. CoreData uses a custom opaque (not documented) format for the sql store. You would be hard pressed to reverse engineer this.

You will probably save a lot of time by rewriting that part for windows, rather than trying to get it working. There really isn't much iOS code that can be reused under windows, unless you have written pure C or C++.